# DNN - Development Websited/Db Migration to Live Website/Db?

Tags: sql-server, migration, dotnetnuke, web-development-server

In development, we have added/removed/edited pages, modules, and changed some settings from the development's portal UI. These changes, of course, were reflected in the development database as well.

I think that in practice, we would need to (and probably should) manually add/remove/edit/install/uninstall pages and modules on the live site to reflect exactly the page/module structure as in the development website. (For pages, we would need to redo them, including manually setting the skin for every single one).

We figure that a probable shortcut is to manually delete records in the database and bulk-copy certain tables from the development database to live database, but then we might interfere with other database-related DNN infrastructure because they might depend on IDs of the tables we're bulk-copying. (I suppose DNN infrastructure in the database are not meant to be touched other than from the website portal.)

Is there a resource somewhere that tells us how we should handle this situation, and better yet, how to set up everything correctly in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

You best bet will be to backup/restore the database and files in question over your production environment. Pushing data from tables in DNN to another DNN database is a great way to get the information screwed up and unrecoverable.